# Writing on NTFS drives (on Debian Wheezy)

Tags: debian, ntfs

I am currently setting up a personal server on Debian Wheezy. My machine is an ARM based architecture (Cubox).

The problem appear when I want to mount and use my NTFS external hard drives.
The mount point is correct, I can access files and folders, I can change owner but it is impossible to write files even as root.

I mount my drives with "mount -o options source destination"
The command mount gives rw option for this mounted drive.

Comment: Have you installed the `ntfs-3g` package?

Answer (score 4):

You need "fuse" and "ntfs-3g" for this to work. From what I read cubox has this in the kernel so you can try:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /mnt/ntfs/
```

Change the paths to suit.

Comment: Normally it is sufficient to install the packages: `apt-get update ; apt-get install ntfs-3g`. You do not need to specify the file system explicitly in `mount` because in Debian 6.0 (squeeze) and newer `/sbin/mount.ntfs` is symlinked to `/sbin/mount.ntfs-3g`.

Comment: ERROR  ".... failed to access mountpoint /mnt/ntfs: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

In my case the NTFS Partition was open by windows (as in windows 8 and newer Fast startup is enable by default )

1- Disable fast startup using the following method:

2-

```
1 Type Control Panel in the search box.
2 Click Control Panel.
3 Click Power Options.
4 Click Choose what the power buttons do.
5 Click Change settings that are currently unavailable.
6 Scroll down to Shutdown settings and unchecked Turn on fast startup.
7 Click Save changes.
```

3-power off the windows and you can now write to NTFS partition (Tested using Debian 9.3 & windows 10 dual boot grub )